# Who decides which US Flag design will be used when additional states are admitted?

Tags: united-states, flag, symbols

In the question [If Puerto Rico becomes the 51st U.S state, would the U.S flag be altered to include 51 stars?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/19814/6511), it was pointed out that there have already been several proposed designs for a 51 Star US flag.

[image: US flag with stars in a circle]

[image: US flag with stars in six rows of alternating length]

[image: US flag with stars in a hexagon]

In the event that an additional state does join the United States, increasing the total to 51 states, who would actually choose which design of the US flag to use? Congress? The president? Someone else?

Comment: These designs should be credited

Comment: @SleepingGod The [first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:US_51-star_alternate_flag.svg) and [second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:US_flag_51_stars.svg) are in the public domain, so no credit is necessary or expected. The [third](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:A_possible_flag_of_the_United_States_of_America_displaying_51_stars.svg) is Creative Commons, which does require I attribute it to Wikipedia user Milan Suvajac (that said, I'm not entirely certain that they *can* put a US flag redesign under CC, but that's probably a question for Law.SE).

Comment: I'm going to channel my inner Al Haig and state that I'm in charge of that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently it's the President.  From [USFlag.org](http://www.usflag.org/the.49.star.flag.html):

> On January 3rd,1959 Alaska was formally granted statehood placing the 49th star on our Flag. Executive Order of President Eisenhower dated January 3, 1959 - provided for the arrangement of the stars in seven rows of seven stars each, staggered horizontally and vertically.

Wikipedia identifies the executive order as [10798 - Flag of the United States](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Executive_Order_10798).  The executive order includes a drawing of the new flag.

The current flag was established by [Executive Order 10834 - The Flag of the United States](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Executive_Order_10834), also by Dwight Eisenhower.